# Обязательные и только для модераторов теги должны быть по возможности переведены на ru.SO (как это было сделано на pt.SO)

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

> [image]
> [image]

Обязательные и только для модераторов теги переведены на pt.SO, не должны ли они быть переведены на ru.SO?

Comment: Вот перевод, чтобы можно было начать: bug – ошибка/баг, support – поддержка, discussion – обсуждение, feature-request – предложение, status-deferred – отложено, status-review – в-рассмотрении, status-bydesign – так-и-задумано, status-norepro – не-подтверждён, status-completed – завершён, status-planned – запланировано, status-declined – отклонено, status-reproduced – подтверждён.

Comment: @EzioMercer, ну не надо старые вопросы переводить...

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему? Разве это вредит?

Comment: @EzioMercer, главная страница завалена старыми неактуальными вопросами. Зачем их трогать?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не понимаю в чём проблема. Нужны новые вопросы, есть вкладка вопросы. То что на главной есть старые вопросы, никаких проблем не вызывает

Comment: @EzioMercer, вызывает и совершенно бесполезно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ты не говоришь ничего конкретного, потому спорить тут бесполезно. Я же просто руссифицирую то что на английском т.к. на ruSO, должно быть на русском, а не на английском и не вижу абсолютно ничего плохого в этом

Comment: @EzioMercer, сообщения о багах для разработчиков должны быть на обоих языках. Про плохое - ещё раз: вся главная завалена мусором - это неудобно. И эти изменения совершенно бесполезны.

Comment: @Qwertiy С каких пор вопросы о переводе мы публикуем на обоих языках? По крайней мере эти старые вопросы, пока что единнственное место, где я вижу что-то на английсом. И тем более если должно быть на обоих языках, то не должно быть чисто на английском. Вопросы, где есть на обоих языках я и не трогал. "вся главная завалена мусором - это неудобно" - кому не удобно? Чему мешает? Мешает видеть новые вопросы? Так они есть во вкладке Вопросы. Бесполезны из-за чего? Из-за того что вопросы уже решены? Тогда вопросы о решённых переводах тем более бесполезны, тогда может их впринципе удалить?

Comment: @EzioMercer, неудобно как минимум мне. Бесполезны изменения потому что они не приносят пользы. Совершенно никакой разницы, на каком языке задан вопрос, который решён много лет назад разработчиками. И заметь, что комментарии под этими вопросами именно от разработчиков - вероятно, тогда транзифекса или не было, или просто что-то ещё было не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я перестану переводить, раз так сильно не хочешь, но это будет так скажем чисто из-за уважения, а не потому что твои аргументы "неудобно мне" или "вопросы старые" хоть как-то меня переубедили

Answer (score 1):

Tags translation is currently discussed in a separate question: [Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/866/)

Also, I've already translated tag wikis and wiki excrepts for all required and mod-only tags.

Thank you for this proposal.

---

Перевод системных меток обсуждается в отдельном вопросе: [Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/866/)

Краткие и полные описания всех этих меток я уже перевел.

Спасибо вам за это предложение.