# Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, мета

На мой взгляд, было бы здорово использовать системные метки на русском языке. Ниже предлагаю вариант перевода. Если вы считаете, что какой-либо термин можно перевести более удачно, пожалуйста, опубликуйте вашу версию к ответу на этот вопрос.

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) → обсуждение
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) → дефект
- [support](/questions/tagged/support) → поддержка
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) → предложение
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) → faq
- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) → важное
- [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) → реклама-сообщества
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) → статус-завершено
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) → статус-не-воспроизводится
- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) → статус-так-задумано
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) → статус-отклонено
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) → статус-запланировано
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) → статус-воспроизведено
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) → статус-проверка
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) → статус-отложено

Comment: "так задумано" с одной Н. Остальное - порядок, как по мне.

Comment: @Vesper Спасибо за замечание, поправил!

Comment: Поскольку почти у всех меток теперь есть *переведенное* описание, я добавил исходные названия именно метками, чтобы можно было сравнить смысл этого описания с формулировкой перевода. Надеюсь, это не ухудшит читаемость текста.

Comment: После принятия переводов обновить раздел справки: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969/181472

Comment: Метки перевели!

Comment: Под страхом мафии.

Answer (score 6):

> faq → справка

Я бы оставил [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Это вполне узнаваемый термин. А [справка](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0) оставить для вопросов, относящихся к справке.

> feature-request → запрос-нововведения

По мне - тяжеловато звучит. Надо побрейнстормить.

Comment: feature-request -> хочу-фичу

Comment: просто приходящие в голову варианты: «новая-возможность», «оказия», «с-оказией», «при-случае», «просьба», «просьба-реализовать».

Comment: @MakarovAV, Думал именно об этом, но как-то оно слишком неформально что-ли )

Comment: @Nofate, мне кажется главная проблема ru.so сейчас в том, что сайт пытается стать сразу таким же формальным как en.so. Формальность отпугивает, а популярности чтобы амортизировать это еще не набралось

Comment: @MakarovAV Для добавления "неформальности" можно добавить к вопросу метку [meta-tag:нытье].

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, хочу такую метку в основном разделе, я мигом бы по ней золотой знак заработал!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, только через *е*, а не *ё*.

Comment: @Nofate Действительно. Поправил, спасибо! (Надо назначить псевдоним).

Comment: Перемен, [meta-tag:мы-ждем-перемен]! (Это из Цоя, если что.)

Comment: feature-request → запрос-изменения

Comment: feature-request → предложение

Comment: @Nofate  Очень-очень добротный перевод!

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос: можно ли назначать синонимы для служебных меток? Если да, то все метки желательно не просто перевести, а **синонимизировать к переведенным вариантам**. Это облегчит адаптацию для пользователей, приходящих с англоязычных сайтов сети StackExchange.

Сейчас многие метки на основном сайте имеют такую связь и это удобно. Например, пользователь отмечает вопрос меткой [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) и узнает, что по-русски это называется [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) (со мной так и было).

Comment: На сколько я знаю, их имена жестко добавлены в кодовую базу. После переименования, попробую добавить синонимы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: попробовал добавить метку [meta-tag:обсуждение], а потом синонимизировать. Получаю сообщение: 
«Только модераторы могут создавать синонимы обязательных меток или меток модератора». Похоже, что модераторы могут назначить синонимы.

Comment: Что скажите, может все-таки лучше переименовать, а затем назначить к ним англоязычные синонимы?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: если честно, я не вполне понимаю, в чем разница между двумя способами. Вроде бы видел, что когда назначается синоним, то метки под конкретным вопросом не заменяются на главный синоним, пока не случится правка. Так?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: пожалуй да, лучше переименовать и затем назначить синонимы. Я в общем-то не имел в виду, что нужно обязательно делать наоборот. Цель — чтобы во всех существующих вопросах метки заменились на переводы без ручного перебора и редактирования.

Answer (score 6):

Перечитала определения меток в оригинале.
Предлагаю

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) → важное

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку все статусы переведены глаголами, то и status-review стоит первести в том же ключе:

- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) → статус-проверяется

либо

- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) → статус-обсуждается

Comment: Все таки, исходный вариант, кажется, подходит больше. Исходная версия слова "review", а не "reviewing", то есть, возможно, метка формируется как "статус-имя_статуса". Название процесса "проверка".

Answer (score 2):

faq и справка — разные вещи.

faq обычно переводят словом ЧаВО — Часто задаваемые Вопросы и Ответы. [См. пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E). Программистам можно и не переводить, но ведь эти метки будут и на http://rus.stackexchange.com, а тамошний народ может быть и не знаком с faq.

*Справкой* обычно называется то, что здесь называется Помощь — статьи о том, как пользоваться сайтом. Но не контекстную помощь–подсказку, которую дают пользователю, который застрял в чем–то.

Comment: Почему нельзя программистам - FAQ, филологам - ЧаВо?

Comment: Справка вроде бы и называется справкой, а не "помощью". http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что переводы появятся одновременно там и там. Надо уточнить. Впрочем, филологи должны осилить одно полузнакомое слово.

Comment: @Nofate♦ 1) Я думала филологи наследуют все, что есть у программистов, кроме меток основного сайта. Если можно разное программистам и филологом, то пожалуйста!  Но тогда нужно делать им вопрос на их мете. 2) Ой, ошиблась:(

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, а зачем? Всегда лучше меньше нагружать мозги пользователей.

Comment: @user244413: мозг любит сходства, но учится на различиях )) Что касается вопроса у филологов на Мете — пробуйте )) Пока там маловато активности.

Answer (score 2):

- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)  → [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment2523_868)

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) → [сообщение-об-ошибке](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Хорошо согласуется с переводами остальных обязательных меток, которые также выражены отглагольными существительными:

- обсуждение
- поддержка
- [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/874/181472)

к нему можно синонимизировать следующие варианты

- [ошибка](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)
- [баг](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3)
- [багрепорт](/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82)
- [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82)

Answer (score 0):

Есть раздел справки [«Что такое Мета и как она работает?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), в котором названия меток уже переведены. Когда будут приняты переводы для системных меток, нужно будет соответствующим образом обновить этот документ.

В данный момент там такой текст:

> Каждый мета-вопрос должен сопровождаться одной из следующих меток:
>
> - [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0), которая означает запрос о поддержке с помощью одной из функций сайта.
> - [ошибка](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0), означающая повторяющуюся проблему на сайте, которая скорее всего происходит из-за ошибки, неисправности или ошибки в программировании.
> - [запрос-функции](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8), предназначенная для предложения новой функции на сайте или запроса изменения существующей функции.
> - [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), предназначенная для сообщений, которые не являются гарантированно верными или ошибочными и часто являются субъективными. Если это не ошибка и не запрос функции, возможно это обсуждение.

Comment: К сожалению, страницы справки переводились не всегда корректно. Я более полагаюсь на выбор здесь, чем на справочный центр, в контексте терминов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: полностью согласен. Этот ответ здесь только для того, чтобы не забыть отредактировать раздел справки.