# Популярно на мете -> ссылка на английскую версию

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, локализация

Наблюдается сейчас на странице с вопросами:

[image: Ссылка на английскую мету]

Не должно ли здесь быть ссылки на какой-либо русский топик? Опять же, перевод "featured" как "популярно" сомнителен.

Answer (score 4):

Так и бывает на всех сайтах. Есть список вопросов [на Мете StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (то есть, Мета для всех сайтов), потом список вопросов на Мете текущего сайта.

Даже на английском эта разница не так ясна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы предложил что-то такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Блок «Популярно на Мете» ("Featured on Meta") заполняется исключительно вопросами, на которых стоит метка [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). Это специальная метка-маркер, доступная только модераторам. Она используется именно для того, чтобы помещать вопросы в блок "Featured".

Вопросы, отмеченные на Meta.SE, видны в этом блоке на всех сайтах сети. Также на каждом сайте видны вопросы, отмеченные на Мете этого сайта. Отличить вопросы Meta.SE можно по иконке в виде синего квадратного облачка диалога.

Не думаю, что нужно разделять блоки для локального сайта и для меты. Более того, подозреваю, что такое предложение не пройдет, т.к. изменение будет касаться всех сайтов сети.

Но вот формулировку, пожалуй, стоит поменять. Поскольку сама метка [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) будет переименована в [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5) ([Как можно перевести системные метки на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/866/181472)), то и строка заголовка должна быть:

> Важное на Мете:

Comment: Возможно, это слишком подробное и разжеванное объяснение для участника с таким опытом, как у автора вопроса. Не принимайте на свой счет, пишу в расчете на медианного участника (у которого 1 репутации).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Я действительно не знал, как работает featured, не обращал внимания, а здесь на глаза попалась смесь русского с английским.

Answer (score 2):

Добавил перевод в Транзифексе как «Важное на Мете». В таком виде хорошо смотрится рядом с «Обсуждаемое на Мете».