# Добавить синоним [ошибка] для метки [дефект] на Мете

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, мета

Дабы не потерялось [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36142637#36142637), выскажусь тут:

> Не надо ли для метки [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) сделать синоним [ошибка](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)?

Поступают также несколько более кардинальные [предложения](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36142678#36142678):

> скорее наоборот, для ошибки сделать синоним дефект

Предлагаю утвердить (первую часть), ну, или обсудить для начала :)

Comment: Добавил синоним. Выбор [meta-tag:дефект] в качестве центральной метки когда-то аргументировал @NicolasChabanovsky. Точных подробностей не помню.

Comment: @NickVolynkin надо призвать его сюда для разъяснения деталей. Тем более сегодня у него по расписанию как раз [Мета-день должен быть](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=36124411#36124411).

Comment: А я призвал уже. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обоснования многих терминов не всегда использовались тривиальные рассуждение, для повторения которых требуется большая ментальная работа. Как результат, вспомнить «быстро» обоснования выбора термина по прошествию многих лет не всегда просто (например, мне крайне сложно вспомнить почему «дефект», а не «ошибка»). Все же, на сколько мне известно, [дефект был выбран](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/866/) на основе прочтения соответствующих [статей на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA) и последующей попытки выбора наиболее часто употребляемого термина.

Если рассуждать в общем о переводах, в профессиональной литературе для лингвистов–переводчиков, встречаются разборы фраз на основе «эмоционального отклика», особенности в контексте понимания языка. Я понимаю это примерно так: человек понимает иностранный язык настолько, насколько слова этого иностранного языка вызывают эмоциональную реакцию, аналогичную словам–переводам родного языка. Таким образом, самым главным критерием для выбора перевода является однозначный эмоциональный отклик на слово–перевод (желательно, как можно у большего числа людей). Сравним два термина:

1. «база дефектов»;
2. «база ошибок».

В моем понимании, второй не вызывает однозначного эмоционального соответствия с термином «bug tracker», в отличие от первого. То есть если рассмотреть все сочетания и примеры употребления слова «bug» в контексте, то выбор слова «дефект» в качестве перевода становится очевидным (особенно, после прочтения Википедии или русскоязычного MSDN).

Comment: ["уже существует"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4953/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5/4954#comment18052_4953).

Comment: @alexolut Действительно! Поправил ответ.